# How to add a responsive horizontal scrollbar to div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a Bootstrap table of fixed width like this,

```
<div class="container">

      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 800px;">
        <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Mickey</a></td><td>Mouse</td><td>5</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Tom</a></td><td>Cat</td><td>6</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Pooh</a></td><td>Bear</td><td>4</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Donald</a></td><td>Duck</td><td>7</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Jerry</a></td><td>Mouse</td><td>8</td>
      </table

</div>
```

When I re-size the window, I want a horizontal scrollbar to show up at the bottom the `<div>`

[Link](http://jsbin.com/jeyaqixeda/edit?html,output) to my code.

Comment: You should also consider removing the `style` attribute from `table` tag as static column widths are not responsive. A bit OT: Please put `thead` around first `tr` line and `tbody` around all others. This is more conform HTML code.

Comment: And: you are using both tags, `css` and `twitter-bootstrap` which are in this context a bit conflicting as CSS is raw and bootstrap is a framework utilizing CSS (and JavaScript). Maybe consider removing the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in a `table-responsive`. Here's the [details](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) about table-responsive in Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 800px;">
        <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Mickey</a></td><td>Mouse</td><td>5</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Tom</a></td><td>Cat</td><td>6</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Pooh</a></td><td>Bear</td><td>4</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Donald</a></td><td>Duck</td><td>7</td>
        <tr><td><a class="cl" href="">Jerry</a></td><td>Mouse</td><td>8</td>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/XGV8aYFiZW

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

Use `white-space:nowrap;` and some padding.

Use `overflow: scroll;`, which adds an extra scrollbar on the bottom, but fixes the wrapping problem in Firefox.

Use `overflow-y:scroll` which is CSS3 and is supported by only modern browsers.